# Drupal 7 Render a Comment Object

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

So this is the problem I am running into. If I have a comment object, I want to create a renderable array that is using the display settings of that comment. As of now this is what I have:

```
$commentNew = comment_load($var);
$reply[] = field_view_value('comment', $commentNew, 'comment_body', $commentNew->comment_body['und'][0]);
```

Which works fine because I dont have any specific settings setup for the body. But I also have  image fields and video embed fields that I need to have rendered the way they are setup in the system. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal core does it with the [`comment_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21comment%21comment.module/function/comment_view/7) function:

```
$comment = comment_load($var);
$node = node_load($comment->nid);
$view_mode = 'full'; // Or whatever view mode is appropriate
$build = comment_view($comment, $node, $view_mode);
```

If you need to change a particular field from the default, use [`hook_comment_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.api.php/function/hook_comment_view/7):

```
function MYMODULE_comment_view($comment, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  $comment->content['body'] = array('#markup' => 'something');
}
```

or just edit the `$build` array received from `comment_view()` as you need to if implementing the hook won't work for your use case.